# libvirt QEMU/KVM guest cannot connect to network (NAT)

Tags: networking, fedora, qemu, libvirt, wireguard

An Ubuntu QEMU/KVM guest created in virt-manager with all default settings and network type NAT can't activate its network. My host is Fedora 35. A screenshot of the guest's NetworkManager log is below.

[image: Guest VM NetworkManager log]

Here is the XML config from virt-manager's NIC tab in device settings:

```
<interface type="network">
  <mac address="redacted but present"/>
  <source network="default" portid="redacted but present" bridge="virbr0"/>
  <target dev="vnet2"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

And virt-manager's virtual networks XML:

```
<network connections="2">
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>redacted but present</uuid>
  <forward mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr0" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="redacted but present"/>
  <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

**virsh net-list --all**

```
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

**brctl show**

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      redacted    yes
```

**ip -br link show**

```
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
enp34s0          UP             redacted <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
virbr0           DOWN           redacted <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
wg-mullvad       UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP>
```

**nmcli connection show --active**

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE
Wired connection 1  redacted  ethernet   enp34s0
virbr0              redacted  bridge     virbr0
wg-mullvad          redacted  wireguard  wg-mullvad
```

**systemctl status libvirtd**

```
○ libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-04-04 05:13:01; 1min 40s ago
TriggeredBy: ○ libvirtd-tls.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ○ libvirtd-tcp.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 36276 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $LIBVIRTD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 36276 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 439ms

Apr 04 05:12:49 host systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Apr 04 05:12:49 host systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
[user@host ~]$ sudo systemctl status libvirtd
○ libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2022-04-04 05:13:01; 2min 1s ago
TriggeredBy: ○ libvirtd-tls.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ○ libvirtd-tcp.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 36276 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $LIBVIRTD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 36276 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 439ms

Apr 04 05:12:49 host systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Apr 04 05:12:49 host systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 04 05:13:01 host systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon
```

**systemctl --failed**

```
  UNIT                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● nvidia-powerd.service loaded failed failed nvidia-powerd service
```

**Things I've tried so far:**

- Checked that I have the following packages installed: qemu dhclient
  netcat virt-viewer libvirt dnsmasq dmidecode ebtables virt-install
  virt-manager bridge-utils
- Checked that the network "default" is started in virsh
- Made sure that firewalld is installed and running
- Checked that virbr0 is in zone libvirt with firewall-cmd get-active-zones

## CRUCIAL UPDATE:

Further troubleshooting showed that the VPN I am using is causing this issue. Launching VM's with the VPN disabled lets them connect to the network and internet. My VPN app is called Mullvad, and uses the Wireguard protocol. How can I make this work so that VM's connect to the internet through the VPN?

Comment: You should make sure in the debug phase that the firewall is not running. Also that there's no Docker enabled and running on the same host.

Comment: @A.B what is the way to disable firewall on Fedora? The machine does not have Docker installed.

Comment: You could just run `systemctl stop firewalld` to stop it (and leave it enabled at next boot). Might not solve the problem, but that's one less thing to worry about until it's working. Once it's working, make sure it works with the firewall running too.

Comment: @A.B I stopped firewalld, then restarted libvirtd, the issue persists

Comment: Is the problem just with this specific guest, or do no guests work?  Do these commands provide any hints? `virsh net-list --all`, `brctl show`, `ip -br link show`, `nmcli connection show --active`, `systemctl status libvirtd`

Comment: Does `systemctl --failed` show anything?

Comment: @rickhg12hs 
`$ virsh net-list --all
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes`

`$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id  STP enabled interfaces
virbr0  8000.525400323f0f yes`

`$ ip -br link show
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
enp34s0          UP             redacted <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
virbr0           DOWN           redacted <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>
wg-mullvad       UNKNOWN        <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP>`

Comment: `$ nmcli connection show --active
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE
Wired connection 1redacted  ethernet   enp34s0
virbr0              redacted  bridge     virbr0
wg-mullvad          redacted  wireguard  wg-mullvad`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1q9rCXvL libvirtd shows as inactive (dead)
@user7138814
systemctl --failed only shows an nvidia-powerd error

Comment: Please update/edit your question with the additional information.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, went into a huge tcpdump rathole for hours on this one. I'm using QEMU/KVM same as you, just on Pop!_OS. Enabling Local Network Sharing fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was using a VPN without enabling an "allow local network sharing" setting. Enabling that made it work.

Comment: Just a thought - might be worth changing the post title if possible to include "Mullvad" as this is a rather specific problem and your solution doesn't come up in first page of results :)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling forwarding with

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

might help.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider adding an explanation on _why_ you think this will solve the connectivity problem described in the OP.