# How to exclude dnsmasq used by libvirt from Mullvad VPN's "local network sharing" block

Tags: iptables, dns, firewall, vpn, nftables

I don't use the local network expect dnsmasq for libvirt. With blocking local network I have no DNS on my VM. For that reason I want to exclude dnsmasq from the local network sharing block with split tunneling using this guide: `https://mullvad.net/en/help/split-tunneling-with-linux-advanced`.

As far as I understood, in my case dnsmasq isn't resolving the DNS of my host machine but only the DNS of specific NIC (VM one). Information about libvirt dnsmasq `https://www.whonix.org/wiki/KVM#DHCP`

I want to disable local network sharing for maximum security, but allow dnsmasq using the netfilter rules from the Mullvad guide, WITHOUT opening the port for other computers/router on my local network.

The only local connection I need to work is dnsmasq

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      dnsmasq
```

And maybe I need these connections to work too

```
Netid  State    Recv-Q   Send-Q      Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port  Process                                                                         
udp    UNCONN   0        0           192.168.122.1:53             0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dnsmasq",pid=1695,fd=5))                                              
udp    UNCONN   0        0          0.0.0.0%virbr0:67             0.0.0.0:*      users:(("dnsmasq",pid=1695,fd=3))
```

my `nft list ruleset` with VPN + killswitch + local network sharing (off):

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
# Warning: table ip filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        iifname "virbr0" udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 60942 bytes 62002672 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        oifname "virbr0" udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 50614 bytes 29575202 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }
}
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 1 bytes 40 return
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535
        meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 1 bytes 635 masquerade to :1024-65535
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 396 bytes 23131 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
# Warning: table ip mangle is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        oifname "virbr0" udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target CHECKSUM
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 50620 bytes 29575670 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 4 bytes 256 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 18 bytes 1064 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 2 bytes 136 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 18 bytes 1064 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table inet mullvad {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority -199; policy accept;
        iif != "wg-mullvad" ct mark 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
        ip saddr 138.199.15.146 udp sport 57632 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy drop;
        oif "lo" accept
        ct mark 0x00000f41 accept
        udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff02::1:2 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff05::1:3 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::2 icmpv6 type nd-router-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::1:ff00:0/104 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip daddr 138.199.15.146 udp dport 57632 meta mark 0x6d6f6c65 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        udp dport 53 reject
        tcp dport 53 reject with tcp reset
        oif "wg-mullvad" accept
        reject
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        iif "lo" accept
        ct mark 0x00000f41 accept
        udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 547 ip6 daddr fe80::/10 udp dport 546 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-router-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-redirect icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip saddr 138.199.15.146 udp sport 57632 ct state established accept
        iif "wg-mullvad" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        udp sport 68 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 udp dport 67 accept
        udp sport 67 udp dport 68 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff02::1:2 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 546 ip6 daddr ff05::1:3 udp dport 547 accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 udp sport 547 ip6 daddr fe80::/10 udp dport 546 accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::2 icmpv6 type nd-router-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-router-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-redirect icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr ff02::1:ff00:0/104 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-solicit icmpv6 code no-route accept
        ip6 daddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        icmpv6 type nd-neighbor-advert icmpv6 code no-route accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        udp dport 53 reject
        tcp dport 53 reject with tcp reset
        oif "wg-mullvad" accept
        iif "wg-mullvad" ct state established accept
        reject
    }

    chain mangle {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        oif "wg-mullvad" udp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        oif "wg-mullvad" tcp dport 53 ip daddr 10.64.0.1 accept
        meta cgroup 5087041 ct mark set 0x00000f41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
    }

    chain nat {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oif "wg-mullvad" ct mark 0x00000f41 drop
        oif != "lo" ct mark 0x00000f41 masquerade
    }
}
```

My dnsmasq conf is managed by libvirtd. See the conf below

```
##WARNING:  THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
##OVERWRITTEN AND LOST.  Changes to this configuration should be made using:
##    virsh net-edit default
## or other application using the libvirt API.
##
## dnsmasq conf file created by libvirt
strict-order
pid-file=/run/libvirt/network/default.pid
except-interface=lo
bind-dynamic
interface=virbr0
dhcp-range=192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254,255.255.255.0
dhcp-no-override
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-lease-max=253
dhcp-hostsfile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
addn-hosts=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts
```

Comment: `dnsmasq` is typically used as a DNS forwarder. I think you want to clarify on whether its upstream DNS server is a public server or a private host in your LAN (for example, your home router), and if it's a public one, do you want to use your VPN for those DNS traffics.

Comment: I want to rewrite my question but I need a bit of help with that I see. I don't want to use my LAN DNS nor a public DNS. If I'm righ the public DNS of Mullvad is closed. I want the DNS of the Mullvad VPN client to work on my VM.

When I disable "local connections" it blocks the following connection
`Proto Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Program name`    
`tcp     192.168.122.1:53     0.0.0.0:*                       LISTEN   dnsmasq`   

I want to exclude this connection from getting blocking with the help of split tunneling. How should I rephrase my question?

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of `nft list ruleset` (with the VPN up) to your question?

Comment: @TomYan Done. Added!

Comment: If my answer does not help, please add the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `resolvectl` to your post as well. Also consider having `tcpdump -eni any port 53` running on the host side, then run `nslookup www.google.com 192.168.122.1` on the guest side, and add the log to your post.

Comment: I use NetworkManager on both host and VM. I can't do resolvectl. My resolv.conf file is showing 10.64.0.1. tcpdump is not working because NetworkManager on my VM can't succesfully establish a network connection. I added your nftables to my host but it is not working

Comment: Actually. when I allow local network, put my VM on. Wait till the network on the VM is established, then block local network with Mullvad again. Now I can ping `8.8.8.8` but not `google.com`. When I do the steps above but WITH your nft rules I was able to ping domains too, but my DNS seemed to resolve a strangely (some websites were'nt properly working). But it was correctly using Mullvad DNS though. When I reproduce the steps above I can also run tcpdump. Do you need to output?

Comment: I installed resolvconf and changed my host default DNS to `10.64.0.1`. No differences

Comment: @TomYan i added my dnsmasq config and two connections I might need to work like `0.0.0.0%virbr0:67`

Comment: On my VM I have the same error as on this screenshot `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/696940/libvirt-qemu-kvm-guest-cannot-connect-to-network-nat`. He has the same problem but I want to bypass if with adding custom nftables

Answer (score 0):

The chains mentioned below should be contained in a separate table, like:

```
table inet allowedLocal {
    ...
}
```

---

It depends on what exact traffics you wish to allow. If you wish to allow only DNS requests from the VMs (and the replies for that from the host), then you should a chain like this:

```
chain input {
    type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
    ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 meta l4proto { tcp, udp } th dport 53 ct mark set 0x00000f41
}
```

With the `ct mark` (conntrack mark) set, you don't need any `hook output` chain for the replies from the host, because they would belong to the same "connection" of their corresponding request and therefore get the same `ct mark` automatically. `priority mangle` would make sure that the `ct mark` is set before the traffics traverse `chain input` in `table inet mullvad` (where the `ct mark 0x00000f41 accept` resides).

Contrary to what I knew/remember, it does NOT seem that you would need to set the correct `meta mark` (`fwmark`) for the replies to be routed as desired, at least not for those from the host itself to a "local" network. (It seems that the actual behavior is, surprisingly, application-specific. When I tested with the systemd-resolved stub extra listener, the replies go out of the interface which the requests were come out of anyway, even if I eliminate any route, including but not limited to the prefix route, that could be in effect to make that happen. When I tested with dnsmasq, the replies are always routed as per the `main` route table, with all the ip rules / alternate tables ignored.)

---

If you want to allow all "connections" *initiated by the VMs* that are *(L3-)destined to the host*, you can remove `meta l4proto { tcp, udp } th dport 53`:

```
chain input {
    type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
    ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct mark set 0x00000f41
}
```

---

Note that the above chain(s) does not make "connections" *initiated by the host* that are *(L3-)destined to the VMs* allowed. If you want to allow such "connections", you would need this:

```
chain output {
    type route hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct mark set 0xf41 meta mark set 0x6d6f6c65
}
```

As a side note, the `ct mark` setting in this chain is mainly for making replies from the VM to be allowed. What actually get the initiating traffics from the host allowed is the rule `oif "wg-mullvad" accept` in `chain output` of `table inet mullvad`. It seems that traffics traverse `type route` chain at a later stage, so even before the new routing decision is made (because of the `meta mark`), the original routing must be allowed as well. In other words, *I suppose* if one wants to (further) filter traffics that have been "changed" by a `type route` chain, they'll have to use another `type route` chain (instead of a `type filter` chain). **(You can ignore this paragraph if you don't care about the details. The information may not be exactly correct anyway.)**

---

**EDIT**: I just notice that `chain prerouting` of `table inet mullvad` actually sets the required `ct mark` for all `iif != "wg-mullvad"` traffics, which means you shouldn't need any of the chain I've given above to allow just DNS to work for the VM. You can try them and see if they help anyway, but now I feel like the problem is probably `dnsmasq` somehow not using `10.64.0.1` as its upstream server, as I originally suspected...